# APK not installed on android devices

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I was making a react-native build for android devices through android studio. Generated a Sign-in APK for it. After build the APK on release mode when I tried to installed that APK on android device but I was unable t install it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONIdH.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this

1. Your minimum SDK version is higher than your device SDK version
2. Your device CPU architecture is not compatible with APK you generated
3. others that I don't know